# How to use limitRender like in rich:autocomplete

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

Below is my code for autocomplete :

```
<rich:autocomplete mode="ajax" minChars="2" var="message" fetchValue="#{message.displayName}" 
                   layout="div" autocompleteMethod="#{suggestionControlAction.suggestionAction}">
   <h:column>
<h:outputText value="#{message.displayName}"/>      
   </h:column>
</rich:autocomplete>
```

But the problem is,all the a4j:outputPanel which are used in this file are also getting rendered whcih i don't want.There is no limitRender attribute in this tag.

So,how to achive this functionality ?

Comment: You want to display limited suggesstion eg:10 or 15 am i right?

Comment: NO....its not about limited sugesstion.I want to restrict auto rendering of a4j:outputPanel components while rich:autocomplete triggers.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed no `limitRender` attribute, have you tried to nest an `a4j:ajax` inside:

```
 <a4j:ajax execute="@this" event="..." render="@this">
```

I have not tried it but this may work.

Maybe you have this issue:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12158